# Need advice on flashing BIOS on crippled laptop

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, flashing

I have a laptop (Amilo A16676) that I recently got as a present from a friend.
The Laptop has an American Megatrends BIOS (Amibios): v1.06c (BIOS) and v1.06 (EC).

Now, I'd like to upgrade the BIOS with a new version, but it seems that isn't gonna be so easy.

Amercian Megatrends makes me use the [BiosAgentPlus](http://biosagentplus.com) tool, to determine which version I need, and eventually do the update.

The Program seems to go scan the computer for capabilities and runs a few tests, and this is where it fails for me: once the program does the "large hard drive support" test, it stops, becomes unresponsive and just sits there. Mouse pointer doesn't move, no reaction from key presses. I have to manually reboot the computer by cutting off power (it doesn't react on pressing the power button for several seconds).

When I'm not trying to fiddle around with the BIOS, the laptop works fine, otherwise.

Where can I download BIOS versions, so I can flash them manually? I'd simply flash it like that, without the extra scanning tool, which only works on Windows anyway.

Comment: Do you know for a fact their is even a BIOS update for this laptop?

Comment: Nope, but either that, or I need the current version as backup.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a laptop (Amilo A16676)

Did you perhaps mean to say the Amilo A1667G? Because I found stuff for that model on the Fujitsu website after first trying a simple google search for what you specified. I found it here:
http://uk.ts.fujitsu.com/support/support_knowledge.html

Click on Downloads on the left, then select Notebooks > former models > amilo > amilo a1667g. And you can find the BIOS and other stuff there. But it appears that the 1.06c version is already the latest one in existence. Check it for yourself but that's the highest version they have listed. You could try one of the older versions if you think it might fix some issue that you're currently experiencing. But you said the laptop works fine otherwise. So did you have a specific problem that a BIOS update might have fixed or just wanted to get a newer version just for the sake of updating? (And I don't mean to imply any negative connotation at all; I like to keep things up-to-date "just for the sake of updating" myself.)

Comment: well, I need at least a working BIOS as backup, as I plan to flash this laptop with an open source BIOS (coreboot).

Comment: Oh. That sounds cool -- the open source BIOS. I didn't know about such a thing. So ... doesn't that link I indicated have what you need?